# Can i use the past simple twice in one sentence to describe two simultaneous actions in the past?

Tags: sequence-of-tenses

*He started to shriek when we[Insert word] the summit.*

I could use *attained* as well as *had attained* in that sentence to make it a meaningful one.

It wouldn't make much sense to use *were attaining* the summit.

> Attaining a height is a brief point in time, and hence using the past progressive tense doesn't make much sense.

Similarly,

*It began to drizzle when we [Insert word]the game.*

I could use *were playing* or *had played* the game.

> Here, *played* doesn't sound right because the rule says that between two action taking place in the past, you have to specify which one took place before the other one.

So my question  basically is this— Can we use the past indefinite tense twice in a single sentence?

Common sense would suggest *Yes*, because two actions might take place simultaneously in the past.

And so by extension, I am required to say: *She began to cry when his father broke the jar.*

But I can't quite say: *She began to cry when her father, say **dug the well.*** [I must say *was digging* or *had dug* the well.]

Is this a valid analysis or a flawed one?

Comment: Can you say exactly what you mean by *past indefinite*? Do you mean the past simple? I'm not complaining, I know different people use different terms.

Comment: Yes, _past simple_

Comment: Also, if your question can be rephrased as "Can I use the past simple twice in one sentence to describe two simultaneous actions in the past", then the answer is yes, of course. More natural would be to use *as* or *just as*: *She headbutted him as he kicked her*.

Comment: Note that *lose one's wallet* is not a good choice for a punctual action, if that's what you intended it as, because there is no one moment (in normal usage) that can be described as THE split-second of losing a wallet.

Comment: @legatrix— Thank you very much. I have changed _lost the wallet_ to _broke the jar._

Comment: Yes, that's better. Everything from "So my question..." is clear and your analysis is valid. Everything before it is rather complicated and not necessarily helpful. For example, we normally *reach* a summit (not *attain*), and, contrary to what you say, it is perfectly valid to say "he started to shriek as we were reaching the summit". The reasons for this are a bit complicated and have to do with the difference between verbs of accomplishment and verbs of achievement. I would suggest leaving all of this out, or editing it, or asking a new question.

Comment: In your example, is it okay to use _when_ instead of _as_? Like _She headbutted him when he kicked her._ And should I say _She had headbutted him when he had kicked her_ or something else?

Comment: _were reaching the summit_? But isn't _reaching a summit_ a point in time rather than something suggesting continuity?

Comment: Check out verbs of accomplishment and verbs of achievement and it may shed some light. http://web.ku.edu/~pyersqr/Ling331/Kearns9.htm

Comment: *As* sounds better than *when* if you want to describe things neutrally; *when* makes it sound like the headbutt was a reaction to the kick. The past simple is fine, though. No past perfect needed.